# Xamarin / .Net Cognito Scopes in AccessToken

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-net

i am developing an xamarin app. Usermanagement is done via Cognito. I would like to use the accessToken for authentication at the api gateway. So I defined a scope which is allowed to call the function at the api gateway. So now my problem: How can I add the scope to the accessToken while login in? I use the .Net SDK. Are there any samples? The only scope in the access token is currently the aws.cognito.signin.user.admin. How can there additional scopes be added?

Comment: Have you checked the AWS Docs? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html

Comment: yes, but I did not find any about adding the scope to the access token in .Net api

Comment: Have you tried using the Cognito Pre-Token lambda function to add the scope?

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/how-to-use-cognito-pre-token-generators-to-customize-claims-in-id-tokens/